# Can I make a Virtual User a Sitecore Administrator?

Tags: security, sitecore

I'm using Federated Authentication with Sitecore 9.1; because of this, all users are Virtual. I have a Group Membership that governs who is going to be an administrator or not.

Creating a user with `Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser()` doesn't seem to have any option for making that user an administrator.

**QUESTION**

Is there a way to create a Virtual User that is also a Sitecore Administrator? Or giving admin privileges to an instance of Sitecore.Security.Accounts.User?

Answer (score 0):

Yes the full documentation is on the SDN:
https://doc.sitecore.com/sdnarchive/Articles/security/Faking%20user%20roles.html

```
    ID myUserID = ID.NewID;
    string myUserName = "Virt";

    UserItem myUser = Context.Domain.BuildVirtualUser(myUserID, myUserName);

    using(new EditContext(myUser.InnerItem))
    {
    myUser.IsAdministrator = true;
    }

    Context.Domain.Login(myUser);
```

Comment: The guide above seems to not be working for Sitecore 9 - it says "Valid for Sitecore 5.X".

Comment: Sorry about linking to the wrong doc but I have done this before. If you still need a code sample I can get one late this week when I'm in the office.

Comment: No worries. I have a workaround, but if you can find a way to make a user admin through code, I'd love to see that.

Comment: `Sitecore.Security.Domains.Domain domain = Sitecore.Context.Domain;
var virtualUser = Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.BuildVirtualUser("johndoe", true);
virtualUser.RuntimeSettings.IsAdministrator = true;
Sitecore.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationManager.Login(virtualUser);`